# Activating Container on Standalone Service Fabric Cluster with Open Network Type Configuration Fails on BeginAssignIpAddress

Tags: docker, networking, containers, azure-service-fabric

I am running a single node Standalone Service Fabric dev cluster. The node is installed on a Hyper-V virtual machine with two network adapters attached to the external host network. The first VM net adapter is configured with a static IP address and is used as the cluster endpoint. The second VM net adapter is configured through DHCP and has an IP from the same subnet as the first net adapter.

I have looked at the topic "Service Fabric container networking modes" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-networking-modes). I have enabled DnsService, IPProviderEnabled and ContainerNetworkSetup. The step 2. I skipped, because it is applicable to Azure Resource Manager configuration. I have configured the network type to Open in the application manifest. The service is hosting a docker container.

When I publish the application to the cluster I get Warning events in the Microsoft-Service-Fabric\Admin channel with Hosting Category.
Here are the text of some of the messages:

- `SFApplication1Type_App6:ebanking2016xg_ContainerPkg@257e8304-637b-4e58-bc13-388542cf6d6c@d526398e-e01e-43fd-b1d4-9cba19bd608c:131816448810648848: End BeginAssignIpAddress. Error FABRIC_E_INVALID_OPERATION`
- `Failed to remove enpoint resource file=C:\ProgramData\SF\vm0\Fabric\work\Applications\SFApplication1Type_App6\ebanking2016xg_ContainerPkg.d526398e-e01e-43fd-b1d4-9cba19bd608c.Endpoints.txt. Error=0x80070002. NodeVersion=6.3.176.9494:0:0.`
- `SFApplication1Type_App6:ebanking2016xg_ContainerPkg@257e8304-637b-4e58-bc13-388542cf6d6c@d526398e-e01e-43fd-b1d4-9cba19bd608c:131816448810648848: End(Setup->EndCleanupServicePackageEnvironment due to error FABRIC_E_INVALID_OPERATION): error 0x80070002`
- `End(SetupPackageEnvironment): Id=SFApplication1Type_App6:ebanking2016xg_ContainerPkg@257e8304-637b-4e58-bc13-388542cf6d6c@d526398e-e01e-43fd-b1d4-9cba19bd608c, Version=1.0:1.0:131816452585647419, ErrorCode=FABRIC_E_INVALID_OPERATION`

...

- `Activate: Activate:SFApplication1Type_App6:ebanking2016xg_ContainerPkg@257e8304-637b-4e58-bc13-388542cf6d6c@d526398e-e01e-43fd-b1d4-9cba19bd608c:1.0:1.0:131816452585647419, ErrorCode=FABRIC_E_INVALID_OPERATION, RetryCount=0`

This group of warning messages continue to appear on a 10 seconds interval. And the application stays in Activating status on the node.

When I do not set the network type to Open, the application activates successfully using the nat mode.

So a couple of questions emerge:

- Is network type Open supported on a Standalone Service Fabric installation?
- What is the required configuration on host, guest, cluster, and node level?